# TideSDK: Chrome relation

Tags: google-chrome, tidesdk

First of all, I'm swiss, so forgive me if I mistake; My english is not so rich.

In tiapp.xml file I can see this directive `<chrome scrollbars="true">true</chrome>`.

It means that tideSDK uses Google Chrome? Or what else?
In other words: there is the possibility of missing functionalities depending the final user's configurations(Google Chrome not installed)?

Excuse me for the stupid question but I did not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome means the look - the outer decoration of the window. Another word might be "skin".
Enabling/disabling tells the framework to add the OSes native window decoration to a window - scaling borders on each side, a title bar with the window name, as well as min/max/close buttons - all this is part of the window chrome.

If you want to create 100% custom looking windows, you have to disable the window chrome.
Heads up! Scaling and moving of the window is automatically handled by the window chrome. If you disable it, you have to handle that functionality by yourself.

This is in no way related to Google Chrome :)

Comment: Hi Cristian! Now it's clear, thank you! And...no, I think the default window is fine like it is. :D